# how to return a custom message in jsp using spring 3 mvc and hibernate validator(jsr303)

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have a project using spring 3 mvc and hibernate validator to validate form object.

I follow spring's [document](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc)

In my controller, I can get bindingresult, which `bindingresult.hasErrors() == true`.

I use `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` to do the error message binding.
**And my question is:**
Is it possible that I can have a more flexible error message display in my jsp web page?

For example, I want to say "the app name **UserEnteredAppName** is not valid. The size should be between **2** and **255**".

In my message.property, I define:

```
Size.appNameForm.itemName=the app name {What Should I do in this brace？} is not valid. The size should be between {1} and {2}
```

{1} and {2} can be interpolated to '2' and '255'. but how can I get the UserEnteredAppName in the interpolated message?

Below is my form class and controller class:

My controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value="foo.htm")
public String handleAppNameFormSubmit(@Valid @ModelAttribute("appNameForm") AppNameForm form, BindingResult result){
}
```

My form class:

```
public class AppNameForm implements IForm{
    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    private String itemName;
    ....
}
```

I find some links which give me some hint:

for example: [How do I dynamically resolve message parameters with Hibernate Validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765127/how-do-i-dynamically-resolve-message-parameters-with-hibernate-validator)

But I am using spring mvc and spring controll which jsr303 implementation to use, I cant find a way to use custom validator, extending hibernate's default ValidatorImpl.

What I am thinking the solution is, I can have custom validator, which will reject the UserEnteredAppName into the bindingResult. is it possible? or I should find another way?

Thanks
Andrew

Comment: FYI, in my jsp, I use spring tags to bind the error message: `<form:error path="itemName"/>`

Answer (score 1):

As of release 4.2 Hibernate Validator provides [ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/api/index.html?org/hibernate/validator/messageinterpolation/ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator.html), a new message interpolator which should fulfill your requirements.

With that interpolator you can refer to the validated value using the place holder `${validatedValue}`. You can also specify a [format string](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) to be applied like this: `${validatedValue:[format string]}`, e.g. `${validatedValue:%1$ty}` if the validated value is a date.

An example for using this interpolator can be found in the Hibernate Validator [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-message-interpolator).

Comment: I am using Spring 3 MVC. So the error message is handle by ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource(spring class). Is it possible that I can use hibernate validator's  message interpolator ?

Comment: You should be able to use `ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator` in conjunction with Spring's `MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator`by setting the following interpolator at Spring's LocalValidatorFactoryBean: `new ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator(new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(new MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator(yourReloadableMessageSource)))`

Comment: An addition: Given that you are working with a reloadable message source you probably should use the constructor `ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(ResourceBundleLocator userResourceBundleLocator, boolean cacheMessages)` which allows to disable the internal caching of resolved messages in Hibernate Validator.