# How to configure custom message interpolation with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, validation, jpa, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I write custom message interpolation. I want that JPA will use my custom message interpolation. Here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-bootstrapping.html#section-message-interpolator I found following description:

```
Configuration<?> configuration = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure();
ValidatorFactory factory = configuration
    .messageInterpolator(new ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator(configuration.getDefaultMessageInterpolator()))
    .buildValidatorFactory();

Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
```

but where I should write such a code? In the web.xml in init-servlet? Can I provide such code in persistance.xml?

P.S. I copy&paste the code. In my case line

```
ValueFormatterMessageInterpolator(configuration.getDefaultMessageInterpolator()))
```

will be change on something like this

```
CustomMessageInterpolator(configuration.getDefaultMessageInterpolator()))
```

see also [How do I dynamically resolve message parameters with Hibernate Validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765127/how-do-i-dynamically-resolve-message-parameters-with-hibernate-validator)

Answer (score 1):

The JSR-303 bean validation framework provides the possibility to configure the validatation framework via XML.

E.g. `META-INF/validation.xml`

See chapter

> 4.4.6. XML Configuration: META-INF/validation.xml

of the spec for details: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/bean_validation-1.0-fr-oth-JSpec/

4.4.6. XML Configuration: META-INF/validation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<validation-config
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration validation-configuration-1.0.xsd">
    <default-provider>com.acme.ACMEProvider</default-provider>
    <message-interpolator>com.acme.ACMEAwareMessageInterpolator</message-interpolator>
    <constraint-mapping>META-INF/validation/order-constraints.xml</constraint-mapping>
    <constraint-mapping>META-INF/validation/catalog-constraints.xml</constraint-mapping>
    <constraint-mapping>META-INF/validation/customer-constraints.xml</constraint-mapping>
    <property name="com.acme.validation.logging">WARN</property>
    <property name="com.acme.validation.safetyChecking">failOnError</property>
</validation-config>
```

Package the xml file with your persistence jar (META-INF/validation.xml) and it should work.

Depending on your deployment packaging (e.g. EAR) it might be necessary to put it in a shared lib in the EAR's lib folder.

The hibernate documentation says:

> The key to enable XML configuration for Hibernate Validator is the
>   file validation.xml. If this file exists in the classpath its
>   configuration will be applied when the ValidationFactory gets created.
>   Example 4.1, “validation-configuration-1.0.xsd” shows a model view of
>   the xsd valiation.xml has to adhere to.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1867

Comment: How can I do it with JPA/Hibernate?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think that you just have to place it on the classpath and it will be picked up by the validation framework. Nevertheless you can still create a validator and override the xml configuration.