# Using bean property parameter in bean validation message template

Tags: java, javabeans, bean-validation

I'm trying to use a feature in bean-validation that I already used in the past, but I don't rembember how and i can't find any documentation.

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

public class User {

    protected String id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Name is mandatory for user {id}")
    protected String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

In this example, `{id}` is not remplaced by instance id.

Is there any way to use any current bean property in message template ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You could use custom javax.validation.MessageInterpolator to achieve it.

Please see..
[How do I dynamically resolve message parameters with Hibernate Validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765127/how-do-i-dynamically-resolve-message-parameters-with-hibernate-validator)

Comment: This is not working. MessageInterpolator receive `String` (= name) in `context.getValidatedValue()` and not the `User` root instance.